# Getting error after upgrading Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I just upgraded Vue to version 2.4.4, and now im getting an warning from Vue:

"Method "_init" conflicts with an existing Vue instance method. Avoid defining component methods that start with _ or $."

Im not quite sure how to handle this, anyone experienced the same, and know how to fix it?

Comment: is it the first npm install or update an older package.json? It can solve if you delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` file, and after run the  `npm install` command.

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory, which part don't you understand? @LakiGeri That's not related at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it was a package that wasn't updated, and compatible with the newer version of vue.. Updated the package and problem solved! :)